# Word for person who has published academic paper

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who has published academic papers under his name.  Example usage:

> "I'd like to work alongside the ________ Dr. Bob"

I was thinking something like "published" (the published Dr. Bob) but I couldn't find confirmation.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there's an adjective to prefix before someone's name to denote that they are a *published author*. With a slight twist to your example sentence, you can use ***published*** in its adjective form to convey this meaning.

> "I'd like to work alongside Dr. Bob, a ***published*** author"

ODO:

> **[publish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/publish)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1.3** usually as *adjective **published***
>   Prepare and issue the works of (a particular writer):
>   ‘a published author’

Comment: To make this answer more specific to those who have published *academic papers*, the phrase ***published scholar*** might be appropriate.

Comment: 'Published (specialist)' would be the usual form, as 'published archaeologist/chemist/physicist/zoologist'


'Published author' normally refers to someone whose profession is writing for its own sake; the subject is not relevant.


'Published scholar' ought to work but personally I've never heard anything quite like it. 'Published academic' might be better.